# adding two numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add these two numbers for an hour and can't get the result in the third text field. Please help me achieve this. thank you. also please tell me is there any add() method in javascript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #cal{
        border:3px solid green;
        padding: 5px;
        width:250px;
        text-align: center;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="add()" id="button">Add</button>
    <div id="cal">
    <input type="text" value=" " id="num1" size="5">
    +
    <input type="text" value=" " id="num2" size="5">
    =
    <input type="text" value=" " id="sum" size="5"> 
    </div>
<script>
        function add()
    {
        var a = document.getElementById("num1").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("num2").value;
        var ans =  a + b ;
        document.getElementById("sum").value = ans;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: they aren't numbers they are strings until you convert to number. There are a wide variety of ways to convert.

Comment: That's what I call a `typical JavaScript beginner problem`. Don't worry, every JS developer had this problem once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input values are strings not numbers. You have to convert them to numbers with the function parseInt() for integers or parseFloat() if they happen to be decimal numbers :

```
var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
var ans = a + b;
document.getElementById("sum").value = ans;
```

Comment: what if they are decimal?

Comment: You use parseFloat instead of parseInt

Comment: You left out the radix; was that deliberate?

Comment: @Teemu that comment was made when answer was using `parseInt`

Comment: @Teemu: no, but `parseInt()` does; which was used in the original answer (edited in the grace period).

Answer (score 1):

#### Check this <kbd>[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xhqq3gd8/)</kbd>

Use JavaScript [***Number()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) Function

```
function add(){
    var a = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    var ans =  Number(a) + Number(b) ;
    document.getElementById("sum").value = ans;
}
```